# MVC3 Html.DropDownListFor and html.EditorFor for same field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am fairly new to MVC but have some decent experience with ASP.Net.

I was trying to look into the possibly having a custom option to my dropdownlist. Below is my dropdownlistfor as well as my editorfor. Obviously both the selected value and entered data won't be stored when the page is submitted. I was looking to see if I allowed for a "custom" option in the dropdown, could the value entered in the editorfor be stored instead of the dropdownlist selection? Possibly not even display the editorfor unless the selection is the custom value for the dropdownlistfor.

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Url, Model.individualPages)
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by generating options for a different select with a different id and rendering a hidden field for `Url` property. try following :

```
<select id="url-list">
      @foreach(var item in Model.individualPages)
       {
           <option value="@Model.Url">
              @Model.Url
           </option>
       }
        <option > custom... </option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="custom-url"/>

@Html.HiddenFor(e=>e.Url)


<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#url-list").change(function(){
              var selectedItem =$("option:selected",$(this)),
                    selectedValue = selectedItem.val();

              $("#url").val(selectedValue);
        });
        $("form").submit(function(){
              var selectedItem = $("option:selected",$("select#url-list")),
                    selectedIndex = selectedItem.index(),
                      itemCount = $("option",$("select#url-list")).length;
                if (selectedIndex == itemCount -1)
                     $("#url").val($("#custom-url").val());
        });
   });
</script>
```